# Rolling the r's that end syllables

Tags: pronunciation

I think that I am ok, but not amazing, at rolling rs if they begin a syllable (onset). (For example maybe "red".)

However if the r is what ends a syllable (coda) (for example maybe "emperor or imperator") I fail miserably.

Also, it seems that I attempt to pronounce those r's without voicing (so sometimes my voicing cuts off in the middle of pronuncing a word)

Am I rolling my r's wrong?

Comment: Welcome to LL.SE. It might be easier for others to answer the question if you specify your native language(s), and maybe also which language(s) you are learning that have rolling r:s.

Comment: Since there is a [very similar question](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/2886/800) on this site, I have marked your question as a duplicate of that older question. If your question is different, please [edit](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/posts/4131/edit) to explain why. It will then be reviewed again and possibly reopened.